# ResultSet to JTable - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, jtable, resultset

I am getting a "Cannot Find Symbol" error for rowData, and columnLabels. Is the reason I am getting this error because there is no value yet for the two variables? I figured that once I created arrays they would be null until the function was called with a ResultSet object.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Testing
{
     public static JTable getTable(ResultSet rs)
     {


     //get data from the resultSet using metaData and place into the arrays

     try
     {
          ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
              int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
          int numberOfRows = rs.getRow();

          String[] columnLabels = new String[numberOfColumns];
          Object[][] rowData = new Object[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];   

          for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
              columnLabels[column]= metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1);
              }//end of for loop

          for(int x = 1; x <= numberOfRows; x++)
          {
          for(int y = 1; y<=numberOfColumns;y++){
              rs.absolute(x);
      rowData[x][y] = rs.getObject(y);}
          }//end of loop
     }catch(SQLException sqlException){
      sqlException.printStackTrace();
     }//end of catch

     JTable table = new JTable(rowData,columnLabels);
     return table;
    }//end of getTable;
}//end of testing
```

Comment: Please improve your code formatting for code posted to this forum. Since you're asking volunteers to help you, it's not asking too much for you to not make it difficult for us to do this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a scope problem. rowData etc are declared inside of the try block and are visible only in the try block. A possible solution: declare the variable *before* the try block.